# Webrtc Support Android 5.0

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing an webrtc app. I find that webrtc does not support android 5.0 (api level 21). Here is the code I get from webrtc library(libjingle):

```
  /**
   * Checks if API is supported and all cameras have better than legacy support.
   */
    public static boolean isSupported(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return false;
        }

        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String[] cameraIds = cameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            for (String id : cameraIds) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);
                if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
        == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY) {
                    return false;
                }
             }
             // On Android OS pre 4.4.2, a class will not load because of VerifyError     if it contains a
             // catch statement with an Exception from a newer API, even if the code is never executed.
             // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209129
         } catch (/* CameraAccessException */ AndroidException e) {
             Logging.e(TAG, "Camera access exception: " + e);
             return false;
         }
        return true;
    }
```

It always return false because Android 5.0's INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL is INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY. So I can not use camera to capture local media stream.

Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented webRTC for android and its support in lollipop and marshmallow as well please check this [link](https://github.com/RWebRTC/WebRTC-Android-Learn)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It couldn't work when I tried to run .apk in my phone because the camera permission. I failed to compile it. At last, I found that someone had already compile it. https://github.com/jitsi/react-native-webrtc       https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc